# Abstraction and Concretion

Tags: logic

I’m reading Evolution of Logic by W.D.Hart and struggling to understand this sentence.
“Abstraction and membership are like inverses of each other. When $Pa$, the predication factors into $a$ being a member of the set of $Ps$; Quine calls this the principle of abstraction. When $a$ is a member of the set of $Ps$, membership and abstraction cancel out, and so $Pa$; this Quine calls concretion”
Here $Px$ is the predicate that applies to some $x$ as in the set notation $\{ x \mid Px \}$

Comment: The basic principle is: $z \in \{ x \mid Px \} \text {  iff  } Pz$

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a rather convoluted way of describing two inferences:

- Going from $P(a)$ to $a\in\{x: P(x)\}$ is **abstraction**.
- Going from $a\in\{x:P(x)\}$ to $P(a)$ is **concretion**.

Note that I've changed the notation a bit; I think it's clearer this way. In particular, I think "the set of $Ps$" refers to $\{x: P(x)\}$. So **if I've got this right** (I'm not a Quine expert and this sort of philosophical analysis can be rather subtle), this is describing the relationship between a predicate and the set it defines, specifically the "processes" relating the two in each direction.